# set the way to the data source in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

My conection string was

```
string connStr = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS
                        Initial Catalog=University11;
                        Integrated Security=True";
```

But then I copied my database to

```
C:\Users\Чак\Desktop\ботанизм\ООП\coursework.start\CourseWorkFinal\CourseWorkFinal\
```

And set it as the way in connection string

```
  string connStr = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Чак\Desktop\ботанизм\ООП\coursework.start\CourseWorkFinal\CourseWorkFinal\;
                        Initial Catalog=University11;
                        Integrated Security=True";
```

But in that case I had an exception

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance 
name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance 
Specified)
```

What correct connection string do I need?

Comment: When you say you copied your database, was this from within Management Studio, or did you copy the MDF/LDF files?

Comment: You really should use SSMS to attach those files to SQL Express. Then connection to .\SQLEXPRESS and specifying an initial catalog should work.

Answer (score 4):

If that is intended to be a "user instance" access to a file, then the connection string is more like:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=YourPath.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
```

Otherwise, use the Initial Catalog to supply a database name registered on the instance.

Comment: But I don't have catalog \SQLEXPRESS. Just simple University.mdf near .xaml and .cs files.

Comment: .\SQLEXPRESS isn't a catalog - that tells it which SQL-Express instance to use. From what you say: **either** register those files in the instance and *use* Initial Catalog, **or** use AttachDBFilename to up just use the file as-is; this still requires the .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I've got an exception that it can't attach database.

Comment: Seriously, it would be a lot easier to register the files against a DB name... But: according to docs, full path should be fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(v=sql.90).aspx beyond that... Hard to guess,

Comment: When I'd done like this it had added the file(I'm not sure but there was not any eception) but When I was trying to refresh it in server explorer it said to me that `don't have access to file because it is in another process`. After I closed the program and then started again - I saw my data. What is wrong?

Comment: The user identity for the SQL Express process will need to have filesystem / OS-level permissions to access your MDF and LDF files.

Answer (score 3):

The connection string (`Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS`...) is intended for hiding the physical location of the database files when you decide to move files. No matter where your files are, the programs that use your database should not care, because logically it's the same database. When you move your DB files, you need to re-point your SQL Express database to the new location, and keep the connection string intact.

Comment: @Артём do you have SSMS? That is the easiest way to work with the databases... (there is a free "express" version of SSMS)

Comment: No I don't. It's caught somewhere dos-virus so It is impossible to install it now. Ok. If I download it what to do next?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов In SSMS choose your database, right-click it, and pick `Properties` from the context menu. In the Properties dialog, select `Files` tab, and provide the updated location of your files there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't change your connention string, you can't access SQL SERVER database directly you must always pass through the SQL SERVER DBMS. The only thing you can do is import/export your data or manage your SQL SERVER to read your database from the new destination folder (but this must be done within SQL SERVER not modifying the connection string).

Comment: But it was done by program when I was trying to add datasource and dataset. And dataset works with .mdf file in current catalog. But program adds to database in another catalog. I can see it with another program.

Comment: Actually, SQL Server Express supports "user instance" daTabases, which work more like embedded databases. You supply the file name in the connection string.

Comment: Oh, very interesting! Didn't knew about that possibility... I suppose you can still take advantage of login/membership functionality, right?